# How can I email the error logs from GitHub runner?

Tags: github, github-actions

[image]

How can I get this error emailed in this exact format?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra step at the end of your Job that only runs if any of the previous steps failed and send an email with the result message using mailutils for bash.

```yaml
      - name: "Notify on failure"
        if: failure()
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install mailutils
          echo "Body with msg: ${{ steps.response.outputs.result }}" | mail -s "Subject" ${{ secrets.EMAIL }}
```

Comment: it results in a mail stating : "All jobs have failed". I need it to be precise like here I need the mail to state that : "Error : Process completed with exit code 1"

Comment: I guess the only option for that is to use Job Outputs, checking for errors at the end of every step and setting the Job output if needed. 
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs
If you are just interested on guarding one specific step, you can simplify the solution by directly getting the Step output on the 'Notify on Error' step. Let me know if this is somehow useful.